# SSD for Sony Vaio-71614M

Tags: laptop, ssd

I want to get a SSD 500 gb for Sony Vaio-71614M, I am willing to spend between 20 and 50 euros. If possible a SSD with a SLC memory.
Do you guys have any advice or product recomendation?

Comment: I can't find any specs or webpage for that model number. Does this laptop use a 2.5" SATA drive or an M.2 drive? If M.2, do you know which types of drives are supported? (M.2 SATA or M.2 NVMe?)

Comment: it uses 2.5 SATA drive https://www.sony.es/electronics/support/laptop-pc-vpc-series/vpccb3s8e/specifications

Comment: Do you want to use this as a caching drive (what SLC is ideal for) or because you expect SLC memory to have higher performance and lifespan? Cheaper SSDs that use SLC memory just provide a small portion of the capacity as SLC (like a built-in cache). A 500GB SSD made of only SLC memory certainly costs more than 50 Euros.

Comment: @Romen I am  looking for both, using it as a caching drive and therefore I expect it to have an overall faster computing performance,but also having a decent lifespan.

Comment: OK, I should have asked more directly: Do you require an SSD that is 100% SLC memory or just *has some* SLC memory? My first question was to bring attention to the fact that a 500GB 100% SLC SSD would not be in the 20 - 50 euro price range.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful with the Intel SSD's, don't be fooled by cheaper prices, we've had many Intel SSD's fail at work or that claim to have a high TBW (Terabytes written over the life of the drive) but have a shorter lifespan.
Sounds like you want a cheap SSD option for your laptop, I've loved my Silicon Power SSD that I bought off of Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/Silicon-Power-Performance-Internal-SP512GBSS3A55S25/dp/B07997QV4Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07997QV4Z)